# How to check if Java is using configured proxy server?

Tags: java, jvm

I have the `-Dhttps.proxyHost=` set in the run command, is there some kind of logging I can enable to see when it is proxying a call?  I need to verify that this is working.

I have also whitelisted a number of hosts via `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=` so I want to make sure it is not proxying these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Using java.util.logging

Create `logging.properties` file with the following contents:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = FINEST
```

Then add `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties` JVM option.

Now you'll see log messages whenever HTTPS connection is established through a proxy:

```
May 30, 2020 2:12:56 AM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection plainConnect0
FINEST: ProxySelector Request for https://example.com/
May 30, 2020 2:12:56 AM sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient New
FINEST: Looking for HttpClient for URL https://example.com and proxy value of HTTP @ 127.0.0.1:443
May 30, 2020 2:12:56 AM sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient <init>
FINEST: Creating new HttpsClient with url:https://example.com and proxy:HTTP @ 127.0.0.1:443 with connect timeout:-1
May 30, 2020 2:12:56 AM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection plainConnect0
FINEST: Proxy used: HTTP @ 127.0.0.1:443
```

#### 2. Another option, assuming you are on Linux, is to trace all `connect` system calls:

```
$ sudo strace -f -p <PID> -e connect
```

After attaching to a Java process `<PID>` with [`strace`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), you'll see all addresses where the process connects to. If a proxy is used, there will be an address of the proxy.

```
[pid 12345] connect(263, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(443), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
```

Comment: thank you so much! Being able to test it gives me a peace of mind. Thanks again!